# Unable to manage my nodejs version using NVM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nvm

I am working on different projects which requires different versions of NodeJs. So I am trying to use nvm but didn't succeeded. It is showing the version now using is . But when I check for node version using 'node -v' it is showing different version.
[image]

Help me out!
Thank you

Comment: What does `where node` tells you, after `nvm use`?

Comment: it is showing 4.2.1 but when I check the node version it is 6.7.0

Answer (score 1):

It's most like a path'ing issue, what does path say in the console.

Talking of path'ing in windows, I use a simpler way to set what version of node to use with what Apps.

I basically copy the node.exe I want, and then inside the same directory I create a simple batch file called `setPath.bat` that has this line in it `path=%cd%;%path%`

This works really well, after opening the console I cd into directory I'm working on, I just call setPath,  and then node is pointing at the correct version for the project.  This technique allows me to also run different Apps on different Node versions at the same time.

I also have this working as services, different services / website's are using different versions of node, I just use an absolute path to the node version the app requires.